# Could GIS Stack Exchange add new question option on menu?

Tags: discussion, questions, user-interface, search

Could GIS Stack Exchange add an option to see  the "newest" questions on the menu?

This way a person can click on that option to focus on new questions.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure where you took your screenshot from but to see the Newest questions on our Main site I use https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest:

[image]

Finding questions with the newest answers is harder, but for that I use https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aanswer:

[image]

Getting the latter is harder than what I would like so I made an enhancement request quite a while ago as [Finding Questions with the Newest Answers anywhere on Site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235102/finding-questions-with-the-newest-answers-anywhere-on-site)